# SIGTERM signal handler not printing to a console

Tags: c, linux, signals, daemon

I am trying to catch the SIGTERM signal and print a message in the handler from a Linux daemon:

```
void SigStop_Handler(int sig)
{
   D(printf("****************** HANDLED STOP SIGNAL ******************\n"));
   printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   signal(SIGTERM, SigStop_Handler);

   while(true)
   {
      //do something
   }

   return 0;    
}
```

The program runs as a daemon, started from a command line:

```
systemctl start abc
```

The deameon will be stopped by:

```
systemctl stop abc
```

When the daemon is stopping, I expected that the message will be printed on the console. However the message is not printed and the command line doesn’t return to the command-promt. It does return after a while (timeout). The daemon will be stopped, but the message will not be printed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two items to consider: terminating the daemon when signal is received, and getting the message.

In the context of systemctl, you want your signal handler to exit the program. Otherwise, 
it will just 'print' the message the messages, and resume processing. Try

```
void SigStop_Handler(int sig)
{
   D(fprintf(stderr, "****************** HANDLED STOP SIGNAL ******************\n"));
   printf("\n");
   exit(sig+128) ;
}
```

Also, given that the process run as a daemon, stdout is not going to be connected to the terminal. Instead, it will get redirected into log file. Also, suggesting using stderr to send messages, instead of stdout (see code above). Also, look at `StandardOutput` and `StandardErrro` configuration entries for your service.

The delay that you currently observe occurs because 'systemctl' wait for few seconds after sending the TERM signal - giving the daemon change to terminate. If the daemon does not terminate voluntarily, a KILL signal will be sent, which will force the daemon to terminate, unconditionally, immediately.

Comment: Yes, fprintf works. However, the service will stop even without using exit. It is like after SigStop_Handler, the shutdown of the service will continue. I assume, that till I am in the SigStop_Handler, the system will not shutdown the service.

Comment: The goal of the signal handler is usually to allow from cleanup, logging, etc. If you do not want to handle this part, there is little benefit to calling signal.

Comment: My idea was to be notify about the stop request for the service. When the request (aka signal) is received, I know I need to stop accepting new data and let the background thread to clean queue, stop and only after that I would call exit. While I am in the signal handler, the process is interrupted. My original idea would that handler would just set the flag to stop listening to a new data and clean the queue. But that would not work, because if I leave the handler without exit, the system will continue in executing the default handler.

Comment: The point is: because it is probably not safe to call threadWorker.join from the SIGTERM handler, how to assure that the SigStop_Handler will wait for threadWorker to finish?

Comment: @query. Is threadWork.join c++ ? If you code it multi-threaded, and you want threadWorder to complete current request (or some other critical activity) you have few choices: critical sections, signal holding, or you can set a global flag ("terminateASAP") instead of exit, and have the workerthread perform periodic check. This goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Also note that if you ignore the TERM, and wait for the KILL to terminate your code, the workerThread will not get any opportunity to react. The process will get killed immediately!